# When i use useSelector or useNavigate, my screen went blank without any error

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

```
const { userInfo } = useSelector((state) => state.userLogin);

const navigate = useNavigate();
useEffect(() => {
  if (!userInfo.mobile) {
    navigate("/sign/");
  }
}, [navigate]);
```

here I just want to redirect the user if he is not logged in

Comment: If there is no route matching `/sign/`, that's what would indeed happen.

Answer (score -1):

that's because since the component you're using useNavigate is not a child of . you can't use it outside router